Setting booleans in LaTeX3
Perhaps I have misread the documentation, but as far as I can see LaTeX3 does not provide a way to turn the strings true or false into a boolean. If you are using keys, then you can do essentially do this using:
\bool_new:N \l__test_bool
\keys_define:nn { mycode }
{
  test .bool_set:N \l__test_bool
}

With this in place, \keys_set:nn { mycode }{test=true} and \keys_set:nn { mycode }{test=false} set \l__test_bool to be true or false, respectively, in exactly the way that I want.
When I first looked for this I expected to find a command that could be used as \bool_set_from_str:Nn \l__test_bool {true} or \bool_set_from_str:Nn \l__test_bool {false}, but this does not appear to exist, even though the inverse command \bool_to_str:N \l__test_bool is available. The places where I want such a command are a variation on the previous example where I want to set \l__test_bool and then execute some other code, along the lines of:
\bool_new:N \l__test_bool
\keys_define:nn { mycode }
{
  test .code:n  = {
    \bool_set_from_str:Nn \l__test_bool {#1}
    % do some other things
}

Of course, it is easy enough to define such a command yourself:
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \bool_set_from_str:Nn #1 #2
{
  \str_case:enF { \str_lowercase:n{#2} }
  {
    {false} {\bool_set_false:N #1}
    {true}  {\bool_set_true:N #1}
  }
  { \msg_error:nnn ... }
}

In practice, I do something like this, but I think that there should be a kernel command for this.  Internally, .bool_set:N does something very similar, so I am only asking why this code is not exposed.
Finally, my question: Is there such a command and I am missing it, or has it been decided that this is not a useful feature?

\bool_set:Nn is available in the kernel.

@Stephen Sorry, poor choice of name. I have updated the post to use \bool_set_from_str:Nn. The \bool_set:Nn command operates on boolean expressions, not strings, so it does not do what I want.

I don't think you've missed anything. From previous discussions, I've concluded there is a notable awkwardness in the handling of keys in some cases. It isn't just booleans, but it is most noticeable there because it is a pretty common occurrence.
There are nicer workarounds than you're using. For example:

\bool_set_eq:Nc \l__mycode_test_bool { c_#1_bool };
use a .meta:n key to pass the given value onto a .bool_set:N and a .code:n key;
use (abuse? misuse?) either .choice:n or .choices: to handle the boolean which is, after all, a very specific and restrictive kind of choice;
use the lower-level parsing facilities instead, though this has never seemed worth the trouble to me.

Alternatively, you can, of course, use a different key-value package. pgfkeys offers very, very slick facilities in the form of both out-of-the-box forwarding and do-it-yourself custom handlers. Of course, there are things which are difficult or awkward about pgfkeys, too. In particular, combining it with l3keys and/or expl3 more generally is awkward. If you can deal with the awkwardness, it can actually work very well, but there is no denying that awkwardness.
As I understand it, not implementing more complex handling or the ability to create custom handlers is a design choice by LaTeX's developers. There are probably good reasons for that choice, but aside from considerations of simplicity, I'm not cognisant of them.
So you just have to pick your poison ....
[Any answer I write about expl3 is highly likely to get deleted later. This one is certainly no exception.]

\bool_set_eq:Nc \l__mycode_test_bool { c_#1_bool }; is what I'd use possibly with an expandable lowercase around #1

@DavidCarlisle but you still have to use something to make it a key?

I'm not sure if I understand.  For use in keys there is .bool_set the question is how to make a bool setter outside the l3key context

Thanks for your detailed answer. I  particularly like your slick option #1, which hasn't occurred to me. I am a big fan of pgfkeys. I didn't like l3keys initially, but they have grown on me.

@DavidCarlisle because the question is about setting up a key which sets a boolean and does something else. in pgfkeys, that's easy to do elegantly. in l3keys, it isn't. so the options in my answer aren't intended as mutually exclusive. sticking to l3keys, you'd want 1 and 2 or 1 and 3, for example. that way you can set up a key which looks like a boolean to the user, even though it is actually set up as a choice key, say. I think it's pretty common to want this?

hmm OK, I see..
